# Why Is it Consider Bad Practice to Use Static Class In Python

Tags: python

In compiled languages like C#, it is very common to create a static utility class with static methods. But in python the common practice is to use bare functions, without a class. Why ?

Comment: So why use a class with just static methods *at all*? What advantage would the overhead give you in Python? Static classes are a work-around where you cannot use bare functions, so why use the work-around where it is not needed?

Comment: In other words, invert the question. Why is it common in C# to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all Python does not provide `static` class (nor `final` or `abstract`* ones), but only "default" classes.
The reason for which is not usual to create classes with static methods is that, since python is based on [modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html), is preferred to "use a module like a static class", since it's more natural and pythonic.
So for example, consider the `random` module, you use it in this way:

```
import random

random.choice([1, 2, 3])
```

there is no `RandomUtils` class, like if it were Java or similar languages... it would be pretty useless.

- using [abc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) module you can create abstract classes